# Swift hiding shell script

Tags: xcode, swift, nstask

I have a simple shell script wrapper on swift project for OSX. When I build the app I can clearly see my ".sh" file in the Resources folder. I thought about renaming it and start the name of the script with a ".dot" so finder hides it but I would like a way to embed or completely obscure the script.

The script is extremely complicated so it's impractical to try to write it inside swift with NStask.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're trying to hide it?

Comment: The shell script is in plain text and anyone can read my code. I would like to hide the magic a little bit and not allow anyone to copy my script.

Comment: Despite whatever efforts you might make to hide the code, prevent access, pirate proof, etc., if someone wants it bad enough they'll eventually succeed/prevail. Going to great lengths to protect an app is often a worthless endeavor, and time better spent making improvements to the actual purpose of the app. Lastly, If your app is worth buying then people will gladly want to purchase it to ensure you continue developing it.